# Sequential compactness implies boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Suppose a set $K\subset \mathbb{R}$. Every sequence in K has a convergent subsequence that converges to a limit in K. Prove that K is bounded.

I want to use contradiction. Suppose K is not bounded, then there should be an unbounded sequence $\{a_n\}$. And I want to show that $\{a_n\}$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Say that $\{a_n\}$ had a limit $l$. Can you prove that after some point in the sequence $|a_n - l| \geq 1$?

Comment: So the information that the subsequence converges to some limit "in" $K$ is redundant?

Comment: In this case, yes. You would need that to prove $K$ is closed, though.

Comment: I find another similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250790/a-sequentially-compact-subset-of-bbb-rn-is-closed-and-bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly this won't work for any unbounded sequence: for example, the sequence $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\ldots$ has a convergent subsequence. However, since $K$ is unbounded, we may choose $a_i$ to be any element of $K$ such that $|a_i| \geq i$; this way, we get a sequence $(a_n)$ with no convergent subsequence.

Comment: thanks, i need to construct a sequence like this. i also find the answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250790/a-sequentially-compact-subset-of-bbb-rn-is-closed-and-bounded

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence that satisfies the following: for any $M$ there exists $N_M$ such that $|a_n| \ge M$ for all $n \ge N_M$.
Such a sequence exists in $K$ because $K$ is unbounded.
Moreover, any subsequence of $a_n$ satisfies this same property.

Suppose for sake of contradiction that $\{a_n\}$ has a convergence subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ with some point of convergence $a$. Then for some $K$, we have $|a_{n_k}-a| < 1$ for all $k \ge K$, so $|a_{n_k}| < |a|+1$ for all $k \ge K$. This contradicts the fact that $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is also an unbounded sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt. I still have a question: If $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded, why there exists $N_M$ for any $M$ such that? If $a_n = 0$ when $n$ is odd and $a_n = n$ when $n$ is even, then $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded but we can't find such $N_M$.

Comment: @Kenneth.K Oops, my definition of unbounded sequence was wrong; I've corrected my answer, sorry.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think this is a way to construct an unbounded sequence that has no convergent subsequence.